# How to build and deploy to Windows Azure using Powershell and Hudson?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, hudson, azure, continuous

I am looking at getting a continuous integration/continuous deployment environment set up for my windows azure project and I was wondering if anyone had managed to (can point me in the right direction to) build and deploy a windows azure cloud service using powershell and Hudson and perhaps has sample scripts.

I can get the project to build using MSBuild64 (I'm running x64 Windows 2008 R2 Standard).
I know 32 bit development works, but assume 64 bit development is better as i understand it as problems will be ironed out on my local box as opposed to once deployed in the Azure environment which i believe is 64 bit. (Please feel free to correct my thinking here)

I assume i have to get the cspack.exe file to package the deployment first as in a manual deployment via the development portal.

Ideally i would like to deploy it locally (with the development simulation) run unit tests against it (perhaps against cloud storage for integration tests), deploy it to staging (run the acceptance/bdd) tests and then switch from staging to production.

Any help with anyones experience in this which will speed this research up for me would be appreciated

Many Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help to get you started: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-running-and-packaging-windows-azure-applications-from-the-command-line

Also see http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/windows-azure-deployment-for-your-build-server-part-2-deploy-certs.html.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I am looking at something similar. The best solution at this point appears to be a custom solution that uses the REST APIs.

Erick